# como eu posso pegar o texto de uma página html usando python?

Tags: html, python, http-request, python-requests

estava tentando pegar um texto de uma página html em um localhost usando a biblioteca requests do python, quando eu rodava o código, ele só mostrava se o status era 200 ou 404.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código:

```
import requests

texto = requests.get("(link do localhost)")
print(texto)
```

Comment: Tenta [`print(texto.text)`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response). Veja também [HTTP Status 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) e [HTTP Status 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

Comment: @Augusto Vasques Muito obrigado!! Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isso por que voce deve tratar o resultado e dizer ao requests.

No caso após voce fazer va requisicao deve fazer print(texto.json()) se caso for um json print(texto.text) no caso de texto e assim por diante, leia a documentacao [Documentacao requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Corrigi aqui, ajudou muito mesmo